# Rails 3.1 assets pipeline and page refreshing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, asset-pipeline

Each time I press cmd+R (ctrl+R, F5) in the browser it misses all stylesheets and javascripts. Next time I click cmd+R it displays fine. Like

```
press(CMD+R) do |time|
  if time.even?
    miss assets
  else
    find assets
  end
end
```

It is very funny, but not in production. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was in permissions to `tmp` folder

Comment: Thanks for actually pointing out how to fix this... that was super helpful.